# Remove Execute Button (ONLI) in ALV Scrren for cl_gui_alv_grid

Tags: abap

How to remove the Execute button (ONLI) from the screen above ALV display in set_table_for_first_display?
I want to remove from ALV display screen, not from Main screen(selection screen) where user enters parameters?

The available events of cl_gui_alv_grid does not have fcode as 'ONLI'.

Comment: How it's currently written, it's hard to understand what you're talking about. Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and see advice how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple.
I just added SET PF-STATUS '  ' before the ALV call and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the class `cl_gui_alv_grid` to show the ALV-Grid and you don't mean the toolbar of the ALV-Grid. The GUI status (execute and other buttons) are normally set in your program with the command `SET PF-STATUS`. Now you can remove it dynamically with

```
DATA: exclude_buttons TYPE slis_t_extab.

APPEND 'ONLI' TO exclude_buttons.
SET PF-STATUS 'MY_STATUS' EXCLUDING exclude_buttons.
```

or you remove the button statically from the GUI status.